# Fisher score error - Length of value does not match length of index?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-selection

I am working on ML problem, trying to compute the fisher score for feature selection purpose

```
A B Y
1 1 1
2 5 1
1 5 1
7 9 0
7 9 0
8 9 0

t = pd.read_clipboard()
```

I am trying to compute the fisher score for each of the feature. I am just following the tutorials as is [here](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/10/feature-selection-techniques-in-machine-learning/) and [here](https://jundongl.github.io/scikit-feature/tutorial.html)

The code is given below

```
!pip install skfeature-chappers
from skfeature.function.similarity_based import fisher_score
score = fisher_score.fisher_score(t[['A','B']], t['Y'])) # error here
score = fisher_score.fisher_score(t[['A','B']], t['Y']), mode='rank') # tried this but also error
score = pd.Series(fisher_score.fisher_score(t[['A','B']], t['Y']))) # error here
```

I get

```
ValueError: Length of values (1) does not match length of index (2)
```

If I pass only one feature as input like shown below,

```
score = pd.Series(fisher_score.fisher_score(t[['A']], t['Y']))
```

I expect my output to have a list of scores for each feature, but  I get another error:

```
ValueError: Data must be 1-dimensional
```

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inputs to the fisher_score method is expected a numpy array not a pandas dataframe/series.

Try this:

```
score = fisher_score.fisher_score(t[['A','B']].to_numpy(),
                      t['Y'].to_numpy())
```